# Download Order information as a pdf from mail

Tags: admin, pdf, transactional-mail

I want to download order information as a PDF form from transnational email.Is there any way to implement this? Actually what i need is after order is completed, need a to send a mail for admin and supplier. For that I have created different email template.My client need this information to be in a pdf format and download it from mail. 
When we click on the admin print we got a PDF link like this  (sales > print)wwww.test.com/index.php/admin/pdf4magento/adminhtml_sales_order/print/order_id/. Is there is any way to implement it on the transaction mail? Please need some help

Comment: Since you are using an admin route the user would have to be log in to magento before they could view the order. However you could use this a template to accomplish what you are trying to do. You may want to add a token to your email url for security (e.g md5 of the protect_code in sales_flat_order)

Comment: yes you are correct. now i need to login to download that pdf. Is there any other way to get order information in pdf without login?

Comment: Create a frontend route and copy the necessary code as needed

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an admin route the user would have to be log in as an admin user before they could view the order.

However you could use the existing code as a template and create a `frontend`d route and copy the necessary code as needed.

For security purpose you may want to add a token to your email url for security (e.g md5 of the `protect_code` in `sales_flat_order`)